# inline form behavior in medium screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an inline form that doesn't float elements correctly in medium screens. In [the bootply](http://www.bootply.com/86WsNP55Au) you can see that when the screen is resized to 666px, the form splits into 4 rows.

The issue I have is with the second row when the screen is less than 660px. It only contains one element even though there is space for the other elements following it. I think the issue is with the second select taking the whole line.

How can i make the row second row fill up with as many controls as space allows?

[image]

Comment: I don't see elements unnecessarily being pushed down. Are you compensating for the `margin`/`padding`?

Comment: Added screenshot. As you can see the two number input buttons are pushed to the third row. There is space for them on the second row

Comment: Are looking for some thing like [this](http://www.bootply.com/RZ5q81sAEk#)?

Comment: Thanks Tushar, in that example though on small screens, you have a first row that only contains two elements but the row still has space for more elements but they move down to a second row

Comment: It moves down because there was width: 186px for the show-tick div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put all the elements in the same div. Try moving them all into the `.first-row` div.

To constrain your controls from being on the first row, use `max-width`

Here's an example:
http://www.bootply.com/U8igeImRHq

Comment: thanks this worked perfectly. but I mis-awarded the bounty and can't undo it

Answer (score 0):

On line 32 there is an in line style that set the width of the 3° input. you can remove it and the form will change its position.

If you need it for desktop i suggest to put it inside a css and than make a media query for tablet/mobile

http://www.bootply.com/P2b26F7LQH#

Comment: in this bootply, when the screen is lower than 540px the issue reappears with the second row containing only one element.

Answer (score 0):

One potential way to solve this that I have used before is by dropping all these items out of div and into ul li combos. Setting the ul to display:table-row and li to display:table cell will equally split the width of the ul between them.

Afterwards I can then target my ul exclusively through media queries to switch when they would take multiple rows or share rows in the display. Once I get the base performance correct I then focus on my li to tweak any styling that is not fully on par.